# How to I display the response from the network tab to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch, response

I am working on a react form and the form basically returns a response if a user is already registered in the database else the form submits successfully.

There's a fetch function that fetches a URL and returns a response.

I do get the following message in the network tab when an existing user with a mail id is present.

[image]

I need to show this message on my screen in a react component.

Here's the fetch body

```
fetch(URL, {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    body: formBody,
  })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I am getting a response which is nowhere close to the response in the network tab. Tried using `json()` too, but I was getting some sort of an error with that.

Need help.

Comment: Hi, can u try .catch(function (error) {
            errorNotify(error?.response)
        });

Comment: what response are you getting can you paste it here

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the response to JSON with the following `.then((response) => response.json())`. To get the response data message you get by fetching the URL you need to call the following code `data.msg` in your `.then((data)=> {...})` function. If you want to print the message you have two options:

1. You can either log it to the console with `console.log(data.msg)`
2. return it in the component by first storing the message in a variable like this: `let msg = data.msg` in the `.then(...)` function and then adding the following code:

```
return (
<>
<h1> {msg} </h1>
...
</>
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
typeerror can't convert undefined to object

after adding the below code. Basically I am checking if the response is empty. 
    ```.then((res) => {
      if (!Object.keys(res.data).length) {
        console.log("no data found");
      } else {
        res.json();
      }
    })
    .then((data) => console.log(data.msg))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));```